# Cordova android build fails immediately [Error: spawn EACCES]

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am just getting started with with Cordova ( PhoneGap ) and trying to build my first project with it, however I am running into a problem with my compilation step- when I try to build ( in tracking down the problem I broke down the `build` step into `prepare` and `compile` and the former works fine as far as I know ) I see this:

```
~/Projects/MyProject$ cordova compile android
Compiling app on platform "android" via command "/media/glenatron/local disk/Projects/Cordova/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
{ [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

Now from what I can tell this is a permissions problem, but having no Node or Cordova experience yet I am at a loss as to how to troubleshoot it. It looks as though it is trying to spawn another process - maybe the Android SDK? - and it is failing.

Is there a way I can ask Node or Cordova to give me more information on what is going on or is there a log file somewhere that will help me to track down what the problem is?

Edit: I realised cordova has a `--verbose` switch and when I activated it I get the above output with an additional couple of lines...

```
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Unfortunately, they don't seem to actually give much more information, like *which* process it can't start.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a permission issue, just execute:

```
chmod 777 "/media/glenatron/localdisk/Projects/Cordova/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/build"
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Annoyingly this was actually happening because I was storing my files on an NTFS partition that I share between Linux and Windows. This means that Linux can't actually do anything with permissions there. Had to move it onto my boot partition and now it works fine. I wish I had been fully aware of how horrible Windows 8 was before I set up the system...

Comment: `chmod +x platforms/android/cordova/build`

Comment: Now the same error occurs on the execution of a hook inside the hooks directory. To fix it chmod 755 the failing. See my answer at another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29467053/21548).

Answer (score 34):

For me, this has fixed it:

`chmod 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle`

Comment: Indeed, this fixed also my problem, but you have a space inside of "Android Studio", so the command should be 
`chmod 777 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle"`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me `chmod 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle`

Comment: Thanks setting the permissions for gradle solved the problem just a small suggestion, please check the gradle folder as the version could be different in your case.

Answer (score 13):

Using verbose like Solidak suggested works.

`cordova build --release --verbose android`

The last command was to access `/platforms/android/gradlew` so i `chmod +x` that file and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Its different for every one, I guess. Running `--verbose` would give you the file that Cordova needs access to. From there you can `chmod 777 <file>`. The command you should run to figure out the inaccessible file looks like this: `cordova build --release --verbose android`

Comment: `+x` instead of `777` is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, I had put the sample cordova project on a different ext3 partition than home folder. Since the partition was not NTFS, permissions shouldn't have been a problem. But when I tried all suggested methods (changing permissions, making everything executable), none of them worked. This problem went away as soon as I created the sample cordova folder in my home partition.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users change the name from "Android Studio" to AndroidStudio. My cordova build was taking back slash() in name of android studio so i changed the name of app.
It is working for me.