# Ionic/cordova sudo ionic platform add android not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

> Nitishs-MacBook-Air:~ nitishanand$ cd myApp Nitishs-MacBook-Air:myApp
>   nitishanand$ sudo ionic platform add android Downloading Default Ionic
>   Resources
>
> Downloading:
>   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-default-resources/archive/master.zip
>   [=============================]  100%  0.0s Done adding default Ionic
>   resources Adding icons for platform: android running cordova platform
>   add android Adding android project... Creating Cordova project for the
>   Android platform:     Path: platforms/android     Package:
>   com.ionicframework.myapp639143    Name: myApp     Android target:
>   android-21 Copying template files... Project successfully created.
>   Running command:
>   /Users/nitishanand/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /Users/nitishanand/myApp Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1155:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:988:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

Answer (score 8):

Try doing

```
chmod 755 /Users/nitishanand/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
```

It worked for me.

Comment: With newer versions of the Ionic command line it automatically does this so make sure you have the latest: `sudo npm install -g ionic`