# Ionic Add Platform EACCES Error

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Whenever I use ionic `platform add [platformname]` It gives me this error

> Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1155:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:988:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
>   lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-
>   lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
>   lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-  lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

Comment: Have a look to my other answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29467053/21548

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting a bunch of errors when i emulate the project (iOS). After 1 day. I found with my boss that if you apply "chmod -Rv 755 inside the ionic proyect folder, it's going to work like a charm!.

Steps:

1. Install node.js, cordova, ionic, iOS-sim
2. ionic start "project name" "template"
3. cd "project path"
4. chmod -Rv 755 * (change permissions inside the project folder scope)
5. ionic platform add iOS (in this case)
6. ionic build iOS
7. ionic emulate iOS

And it will work.

Hope if this helps

Answer (score 30):

It seems that the unpacked project has incorrect permissions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456471/ionic-cordova-sudo-ionic-platform-add-android-not-working/29467053#29467053) suggested to  change the permissions of `hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js` to 755. But the [solution](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-ios-error/20262/9) from the [Ioinc forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-ios-error/20262/9) showed another easy way to solve this -- just run

```
ionic hooks add
```

after you create the project and change to your project directory. Then run:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

will success without errors.

Comment: this is the best solution, but you have to give permission after to specific files and to generated folders. so on the root of the project put "chmod -r 777 *"

Comment: Life Saver, Thank You!