# Ionic Framework Error: Failed to install 'com.ionic.keyboard'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Just started trying out ionic framework and I'm facing a little bit of trouble when I want to add the android platform. When I run the command:

```
ionic platform add android
```

I get the following

```
Done adding default Ionic resources
Adding icons for platform: android
running cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.ionicframework.tester166478
    Name: tester
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.0.0
Running command: "/media/denny/New Volume/projects/mobile/tester/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js" "/media/denny/New Volume/projects/mobile/tester"
Installing "com.ionic.keyboard" for android
Failed to install 'com.ionic.keyboard':Error: /media/denny/New Volume/projects/mobile/tester/platforms/android/cordova/version: Command failed with exit code EACCES
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
Error: /media/denny/New Volume/projects/mobile/tester/platforms/android/cordova/version: Command failed with exit code EACCES
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
```

What could be causing the error above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, the platform adding fails because of missing permissions

```
Command failed with exit code EACCES
```

when trying to create a folder `/media/denny/New Volume/projects/mobile/tester/platforms/android/cordova/version`.

If you are running Mac, you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29528766/1744702) answer by user *holmescn*.

If you are running Linux, try to run

```
chmod -r 777 *
```

on your projects root to get enough permissions.

Comment: @Denny: Added usual solution for Linux.

Comment: @JeremyWilken: Shouldn't cause too much on your personal Linux machine under code repo.

Comment: Low risk perhaps, but its still allowing global permissions on files inside and that is a bad practice no matter what. You should fix the permissions to the proper users and rights.