# cordova platform add android: Spawn EACCES error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am facing this error when adding platform android to cordova project.

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
    at exports.spawn (/home/syed.furqan/Desktop/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
```

Cordova version: 6.4.0
Node version: v6.9.1
Npm version: 3.10.8

Kindly help me i am using cordova first time.

Comment: Hi **Furqan**, I also faced problem in my mac. To resolve that issue I change the permission of my app folder to chmod 777 or if you are using the mac or liniux system. You may try with the **sudo** command. I hope that will work for you.

Comment: @Hiro Thanks for your response I am using Ubuntu. Kindly tell me which permission I need to change. Can you tell me the command?

Comment: Can you please try this command **sudo chmod 755 -R /directory**.

Comment: unfortunately still same issue. :(

Comment: Mine was due to permission issue in android-sdk folder.
Fixed it with chmod 777 -R ~/android-sdk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova android build fails immediately \[Error: spawn EACCES\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109929/cordova-android-build-fails-immediately-error-spawn-eacces)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to go into the directory where `hooks`, `platforms`, and `plugins` live (along with other files and directories) and run this:

```
chmod -R 777 .
```