# Ionic2 issue while building app

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm learning to code in Ionic2. While building the app using "Cordova run android" command I'm getting **Subproject Path: CordovaLib Error: spawn EACCES** this issue. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

[image: Issue while talking build of the ionic2 project] Even after executing "sudo Cordova run android -d" I'm getting the same error. I tried setting Android home path too.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D12Zu.png)

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109929/cordova-android-build-fails-immediately-error-spawn-eacces

Comment: I tried with the solution "chmod 777 "/media/glenatron/local disk/Projects/Cordova/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/build"" in the link but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: run this command and build. sudo chown -R username /Users/username/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/

Comment: @NandhiniB Thats not your project path, try this "chmod 777  $HOME/Desktop/wishsample/platforms/android/cordova/build".

Comment: I tried with this command too, I'm getting the same issue.