# ionic spawn EACCESS error on MacInCloud build agent

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up a build definition for an ionic app using VSTS and a [Mac in cloud](https://portal.macincloud.com/select/#/plans) hosted build agent. The ionic app in this case is an ionic v1 app. The build tasks are as follows.

1. install npm packages (working)
2. install bower packages (working)
3. run gulp tasks (working)
4. ionic state reset (working)
5. ionic hooks add (working)
6. ionic platform add android (working)
7. ionic compile android (***Error: spawn EACCES***)

I have run this build against my personal Macbook and it succeeds.
I have also run chmod -R 777 "/Users/*******/myagent/_work"

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer   6628 Nov  8 08:52 CustomerApp.jsproj
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer    932 Nov  8 08:52 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer    214 Nov  8 08:52 bower.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer    461 Nov  8 08:52 build.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer   6245 Nov  8 08:52 config.xml
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer      0 Nov  8 08:52 git
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer   1395 Nov  8 08:52 gulpfile.js
drwxrwxrwx    8 *******  _developer    272 Nov  8 08:52 hooks
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer    159 Nov  8 08:52 ionic.config.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer    159 Nov  8 08:52 ionic.project
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer      2 Nov  8 08:52 jsconfig.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer   2280 Nov  8 08:52 netwatch.keystore
drwxrwxrwx  339 *******  _developer  11526 Nov  8 08:53 node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer   1960 Nov  8 08:55 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    5 *******  _developer    170 Nov  8 08:56 platforms
drwxr-xr-x   15 *******  _developer    510 Nov  8 08:55 plugins
drwxrwxrwx   20 *******  _developer    680 Nov  7 16:51 res
drwxrwxrwx    6 *******  _developer    204 Nov  8 08:52 resources
drwxrwxrwx   13 *******  _developer    442 Nov  8 08:52 scss
-rwxrwxrwx    1 *******  _developer     28 Nov  8 08:52 taco.json
drwxrwxrwx    3 *******  _developer    102 Nov  8 08:52 typings
drwxrwxrwx   12 *******  _developer    408 Nov  8 08:52 www
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "Mac in cloud hosted build agent"? There are Hosted vs2017, Hosted Linux and Hosted agent, no mac in cloud hosted build agent. Set system.debug to true and queue build, then share the detail log on the OneDrive. On the other hand, you may check the permission if you are using private build agent (Change build agent account to your account) [Cordova android build fails immediately Error: spawn EACCES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109929/cordova-android-build-fails-immediately-error-spawn-eacces)

Comment: Mac in cloud provide hosted OSX VMs. https://portal.macincloud.com/select/#/plans

Comment: This is the private build agent that provided by 3rd user/company, I recommend you setup a private build agent on your local machine. [Deploy an agent on macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-osx)

Comment: As stated above I have tried setting up a build agent on my personal Mac and the build works successfully. Any posts I have read about this problem refer to user access to given files and folders. But I have given full read and write to the user for all project folders

Comment: Can you logon to that machine through remote desktop Connection? How do you set the permission?

Comment: yes they provide RDP profiles to connect. I set the permissions by running the chmod command that i have stated in the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158598/discussion-between-psycho-and-starain-msft).

Comment: Can you build/compile the project via command manually on that machine?

Comment: No, it fails at the same location.

Comment: So, the issue is related to mac in cloud environment and ionic project instead of VSTS. There is Hosted macOS Preview agent, you can try it with this agent and check the result

Comment: So yes the "Hosted macOS Preview" agent does work but still requires the chmod command before running the build command. Just does not work on a mac in cloud agent

Comment: Hosted macOS Preview agent is the official agent, I post a answer, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Hosted macOS Preview agent instead, which is official agent.