# Application error with deployed Heroku app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, babeljs

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku but I've got error after deploying. I've read other posts, but none of them are similar to my problem.

Can anyone help me spot the issue?

This is the log:

```
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495800+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js:193,24]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495801+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable invariant [./~/react-dom/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js:31,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495801+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:49,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495802+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:52,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495802+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:53,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495803+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:58,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495803+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:60,10]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495804+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable owner [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:53,12]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495804+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable ownerName [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:54,12]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495805+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable warned [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:58,12]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495806+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable warnings [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:60,14]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495806+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable warning [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:12,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495807+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable styleWarnings [./~/react-dom/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js:15,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495807+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:30,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495808+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:30,45]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495808+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:31,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495809+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:51,13]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495809+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:51,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495810+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:53,13]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495810+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always true [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:53,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495811+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable owner [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:31,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495812+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable ReactCurrentOwner [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:13,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495812+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable invariant [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:18,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495813+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable warning [./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js:19,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495813+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:38,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495814+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:39,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495815+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:63,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495816+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:64,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495817+00:00 app[web.1]: Boolean && always false [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:18,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495817+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:18,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495818+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:24,2]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495819+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable KeyEscapeUtils [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:12,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495819+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable warning [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:14,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495820+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable ReactComponentTreeHook [./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js:16,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495820+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js:69,33]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495821+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable invariant [./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js:14,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495821+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js:19,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495822+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js:19,43]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495823+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js:20,2]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495826+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable ReactElementValidator [./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js:20,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495829+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js:31,43]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495827+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react/lib/lowPriorityWarning.js:27,43]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495827+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/lowPriorityWarning.js:27,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495828+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react/lib/lowPriorityWarning.js:28,2]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495828+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable printWarning [./~/react/lib/lowPriorityWarning.js:28,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495829+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable invariant [./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js:14,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495830+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:106,12]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495830+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:106,51]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495831+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:107,10]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495832+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:109,12]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495832+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:129,10]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495833+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:134,8]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495833+00:00 app[web.1]: Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:135,10]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495834+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:142,15]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495834+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always true [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:142,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495835+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable mapsAsChildrenAddendum [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:107,14]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495836+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable mapsAsChildrenOwnerName [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:109,16]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495836+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable name [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:135,14]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495837+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable ReactCurrentOwner [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:13,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495837+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable invariant [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:17,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495838+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable warning [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:19,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495838+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable didWarnAboutMaps [./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:35,4]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495839+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unused variable curPlaceHolder [./~/socket.io-parser/binary.js:63,6]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495840+00:00 app[web.1]: Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [./~/wtf-8/wtf-8.js:5,19]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495840+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/wtf-8/wtf-8.js:5,19]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495841+00:00 app[web.1]: Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [./~/wtf-8/wtf-8.js:8,18]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495842+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition left of && always true [./~/wtf-8/wtf-8.js:213,2]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495844+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./public/src/scss/index.scss:12,0]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495842+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/style-loader/addStyles.js:24,0]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495841+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/wtf-8/wtf-8.js:8,18]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495843+00:00 app[web.1]: Dropping unreachable code [./~/style-loader/addStyles.js:25,0]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495843+00:00 app[web.1]: Condition always false [./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./public/src/scss/index.scss:10,0]
2017-12-11T05:53:56.495845+00:00 app[web.1]: Side effects in initialization of unused variable update [./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./public/src/scss/index.scss:7,0]
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620478+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: spawn EACCES
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620488+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620490+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:372:9)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620489+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:302:11)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620490+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:152:24
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620492+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto._getFfmpegPath (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:90:14)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620493+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto.availableFormats.proto.getAvailableFormats (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:517:10)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620492+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto._spawnFfmpeg (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:132:10)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:568:14
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620495+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2017-12-11T05:54:22.620496+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16 code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
2017-12-11T05:54:28.484964+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.33.225.21 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:54:28 GMT] "GET /download?v=7aeI3c-jLnw HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
2017-12-11T05:54:28.481711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/download?v=7aeI3c-jLnw" host=ultramendoza-mp3.herokuapp.com request_id=8cf8d789-101b-4c51-882c-0b994a2b1e53 fwd="201.210.244.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-12-11T05:54:52.536326+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.63.101.233 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:54:52 GMT] "GET /download?v=7aeI3c-jLnw HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
2017-12-11T05:54:52.534534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/download?v=7aeI3c-jLnw" host=ultramendoza-mp3.herokuapp.com request_id=8cd2bb50-8c1e-41df-b6ff-a5ffb469a2bf fwd="201.210.244.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-12-11T05:54:53.116203+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.99.177.132 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:54:53 GMT] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 150 "https://ultramendoza-mp3.herokuapp.com/download?v=7aeI3c-jLnw" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
2017-12-11T05:54:53.112390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ultramendoza-mp3.herokuapp.com request_id=762a3afc-dd03-4536-a651-3d76d0693a17 fwd="201.210.244.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403901+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: spawn EACCES
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403916+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403917+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:302:11)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:372:9)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:152:24
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403920+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto._getFfmpegPath (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:90:14)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403921+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto._spawnFfmpeg (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:132:10)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.proto.availableFormats.proto.getAvailableFormats (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:517:10)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js:568:14
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2017-12-11T05:55:48.403925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16 code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
2017-12-11T05:56:18.324251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/download?v=jRGWXq5WVzY" host=ultramendoza-mp3.herokuapp.com request_id=ebf533f1-057f-430d-abcb-6a553b1d1ff8 fwd="201.210.244.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-12-11T05:56:18.327340+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.144.205.236 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:56:18 GMT] "GET /download?v=jRGWXq5WVzY HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
2017-12-11T05:58:57.415810+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:58:57 GMT] "GET /api/status HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)"
2017-12-11T05:58:57.418665+00:00 app[web.1]: Ping response { upTime: 300083 }
2017-12-11T06:03:57.510427+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 11 Dec 2017 06:03:57 GMT] "GET /api/status HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)"
2017-12-11T06:03:57.512242+00:00 app[web.1]: Ping response { upTime: 600176 }
```

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109929/cordova-android-build-fails-immediately-error-spawn-eacces

Comment: But how do I change permissions on a remote from Heroku?